# Are there video materials of Vedic scriptures describing states of consciousness?

Tags: vedas, philosophy, dream, mind

I would like to know if there are video materials of explained Vedic texts (knowledge) on the internet? Specifically the knowledge about states of consciousness.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you question but thought this may help you. You can read http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/2 and http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/14 for insight into body, mind, soul and other psychological aspects.

Comment: are you looking for only videos of explanations vedic texts that explain the subconscious and superconsciousness? or are you looking for any material on this subject such as sayings  by saints, yogis and gurus, which are plenty and easy to obtain from YouTube?

Comment: I am looking only only for those that explain human psyche, body, subconscious and superconsciousness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The states of consciousness you're looking for are described in the Mandukya Upanishad of the Atharvana Veda, which you can read [here](http://www.advaita.it/library/mandukya.htm):

> 2. All this is certainly Brahman. This Self is Brahman. This Self, as such, is possessed of four quarters.
> 3. (The Self) seated in the waking state and called Vaisvanara who, possessed of the consciousness of the exterior, and seven limbs and nineteen mouths, enjoys the gross objects, is the first quarter.
> 4. (The Self) seated in the state of dream and called Taijasa who, possessed of the consciousness of the interior, and seven limbs and nineteen mouths, enjoys the subtle objects, is the second quarter.
> 5. Where the sleeper desires not a thing of enjoyment and sees not any dream, that state is deep sleep. (The Self) seated in the state of deep sleep and called Prajna, in whom everything is unified, who is dense with consciousness, who is full of bliss, who is certainly the enjoyer of bliss, and who is the door to the knowledge (of the preceding two states), is the third quarter.
> 6. This is the Lord of all; this is omniscient; this is the in-dwelling controller (of all); this is the source and indeed the origin and dissolution of all beings.
> 7. The Fourth is thought of as that which is not conscious of the internal world, nor conscious of the external world, nor conscious of both the worlds, nor dense with consciousness, nor simple consciousness, nor unconsciousness, which is unseen, actionless, incomprehensible, uninferable, unthinkable, indescribable, whose proof consists in the identity of the Self (in all states), in which all phenomena come to a cessation, and which is unchanging, auspicious, and non-dual. That is the Self; that is to be known.

"The Fourth" state, known as [Turiya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turiya), is what is sometimes called "supeconsciousness".  In any case, naturally the videos that would describe these states of consciousness are videos that explain the Mandukya Upanishad.  Note that the vast majority of such videos will be made by members of the Advaita Vedanta school of Hindu philosophy, because they are the ones that give the most importance to the Mundakya Upanishad.

So without further ado, here are some videos that give explanations of the Mandukya Upanishad:

1. [This series](http://youtu.be/hqWXsj2xZg4?list=PLEF1719C37C7BA62E) of eight lectures on the Mandukya Upanishad by the late yogi Swami Rama
2. [This lecture](http://youtu.be/eGKFTUuJppU) and [this lecture](http://youtu.be/F0dugc4TrlE) on the Mandukya Upanishad by Swami Sarvapriyananda
3. This [series of lectures](http://youtu.be/ildR9YOkaTQ?list=PLWjpkY4mU2RCNFihyi0mVZPW7yY2GmO5Z) and [this series of lectures](http://youtu.be/TKWipKRJCC8?list=PLWjpkY4mU2RBzpYlH0n-d0Vq7lL_GElOB) by Swamini Atmaprakashananda on chapters 3 and 4 of Gaudapada's Advaita commentary on the Mandukya Upanishad

Out of these, number 2 is the shortest.  By the way, I also found [this video](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=TcX-CBrF9m4) which claims to discuss how to achieve superconsciousness through meditation, but it may be of dubious accuracy.

Answer (score 5):

There are many videos floating on You-tube. I am not sure whether they are explaining it correctly or not but here are few of them. I will try to explore more if you want.

- **The complete Vedas - Part 1:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SgR9sdy6y8A
- **Rig Veda - Complete chanting:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xCQCSN38KYY
- **The Vedas- With English Meanings:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UUsuqT-ziig
- **Vedic theories of the universe !!! ( ancient indian scriptures ):** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEca1MiE4GA
- **Scientific Verification of Vedic Knowledge--Full Length:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ud1oEFfOrbQ
- **Vedas - Universe Creation:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ofdJ5sZIVbI
- **Human Creation according to Vedas:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uRjmmZIU-mY
- **Vedic Path to Health - Improve your Memory and Intellect:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKn2wP6JCFQ

Comment: Hindu psychology recognized three states of mind: the unconscious or the subconscious, the conscious, and the superconscious. I would like videos of states of mind or psyche explained.