# Glory of the name of Shri Ram by Shri Krishna

Tags: krishna, rama, name

In which scripture has the **glory of the name Shri Ram been told by Shri Krishna?**

Answer (score 2):

**सीतानाथ समारम्भां रामानन्दार्य मध्यमाम्।
अस्मदाचार्य पर्यन्तां वन्दे श्रीगुरू परम्पराम् ।।**

The description of the glory of the name Śrī Rāma by Lord Śrī Krishnā is found in many texts. But mainly it is mentioned a lot in Padmā Purān and Ādi Purān.

Now we will see the glory of the name of Śrī Rāma told by Śrī Krishnā to Śrī Arjunā in Ādi Purān.

First of all, I humbly request with folded hands that please come out of this mindset that Śrī Rāma and Śrī Krishnā are different. Vedās have called Śrī Rāma and Śrī Krishnā the same, the two are not different.

**As quoted by Vedās itself;**

> यो रामः कृष्णतामेत्य सार्वात्म्यं प्राप्य लीलया . अतोषयद्देव्मौनिपटलं
> तं नतोऽस्म्यहम्

**(Yajurvedā Shrüti Kríshnöpanishād 1.1)**

That Rāma, who having transformed himself (incarnated) as Krishnā, attained Sarvaatmaktaa (सार्वभौमिकता) by his very lila (divine exploits, pastimes); and thus deities-sages-masses were completely satisfied on this earth . I make prostration before that same Śrī Rāma.

So let's start with Ādi Purāna's discription regarding the glory of the name of Śrī Rāma by Śrī Krishnā himself.

*आदिपुराणे श्रीकृष्णवाक्यमर्जुनं प्रति~
"Śrī Krishna's sentence towards Arjuna in Adipuran"*

> रामनाम सदा ग्राही रामनाम प्रियः सदा ।
>
> भक्तिस्तस्मै प्रदातव्या न च मुक्तिः कदाचन ॥

O Arjunā, I give devotion to those who always chant the name of Śrī Rāma and to whom the name of Śrī Rāma is dear, I never give salvation even by mistake. (Means I provide them more Power to do Bhakti).

```
गायन्ति रामनामानि वैष्नवाश्च युगे युगे।

त्यस्वा च सर्वकर्माणि धर्माणि च कपिध्वना ।।
```

O Arjunā, in every age, Vaishnavā people keep singing the name of Śrī Rāma, leaving all deeds and religions.

> रामनामैव नामैव रामनामैव केवलम्।
>
> गतिस्तेषां गतिस्तेषां गतिस्तेषां सुनिश्चितम् ॥

For those Vaishnavās, the name of Śrī Rāma is definitely the ultimate goal, that is, the life of Vaishnavas is only the name of Śrī Rāma.

> श्रद्धया हेलया नाम वदन्ति मनुजा भुवि ।
>
> तेषां नास्ति भयं पार्थ रामनामप्रसादतः ॥

O son of Pritha, Arjunā, who chants the name of Śrī Rāma on earth with reverence or disrespect, by the grace of Śrī Rāma Maharaj, he has no fear of any kind anywhere.

> रामनाम रता यत्र गच्छन्ति प्रेम सम्प्लुताः ।  भक्तांस्ताननुगच्छन्ति
> मुक्तय: स्तुतिभिस्सह ।।

Wherever the devotees of Śrī Rāma who are immersed in Bhagwat love go, the five types of Freedom (Mukti) follow those devotees praising them in different ways.

> मानवा ये सुधासारं रामनाम जपन्ति हि ।
>
> ते धन्या मृत्यु संत्रासरहिता रामवल्लभा ।।

Those who chant the name of Śrī Rāma as a torrential shower of human nectar. Those people are blessed, free from the fear of death and very dear to Lord Śrī Rāma.

> नामैव परमा मुक्तिनमैव परमा गतिः।
>
> नामैव परमा शान्तिनमैिव परमा मतिः।।
>
> नामैव परमा भक्तिर्नामैव परमा धृतिः।
>
> नामैव परमा प्रीतिर्नामैव परमा स्मृतिः॥
>
> नामैव परमं पुण्यं नामैव परमं तपः।
>
> नामैव परमो धर्मो नामैव परमो गुरुः।।
>
> नामेव परमं ज्ञानं नामैव चाखिलं जगत्।
>
> नामैव जीवनं जन्तोनमैव विपुलं धनम्।
>
> नामैव जगतां सत्यं नामैव जगतां प्रियम्।
>
> नामैव जगतां ध्यानं नामैव जगतां परम् ।।
>
> नामैव शरणं जन्तोर्नामैव जगतां गुरुः।
>
> नामैव जगतां बीजं नामैव पावनं परम् ॥

Hey Arjun! The name of Śrī Rāma is the ultimate salvation, the ultimate moksha, the ultimate peace, the ultimate wisdom, the ultimate devotion, the ultimate patience, the ultimate love, the ultimate memory, the ultimate virtue, the ultimate penance, the ultimate religion, the ultimate Guru, Absolute knowledge of the whole world, the life of Jeevā, abundant wealth, the true substance in the world, the only lover in the world, the only object of meditation in the world forever and beyond the world, the only refuge of the living being, the name of Śrī Rāma is the refuge of the world, the Jagadguru, the seed of the creation and the one who gives the ultimate status.

> रामनाम रता ये च ते ये श्रीरामभानुकाः।
>
> तेषां संदर्शनादेव भवेद्भक्ती रसात्मिका ।।

Those who are constantly engaged in the chanting of the name of Shri Ram, they are certainly passionate devotees of Shri Ram. Rāsik devotion is revealed only by the darshan of his devotees.

> कामादि गुण संयुक्तानाममात्रक बान्धवाः ।
>
> प्रीतिं कुर्वन्ति ते पार्थ न तथा जित षड्गुणः।।

Hey Partha! Those who, despite being attached to the vices of lust, consider the name of Shri Ram as their everything. The way those people love me, those who conquer the vices of lust and anger cannot do the same love.

> तं देशं पतितं मन्ये यत्र नास्ति सु वैष्णवः।
>
> रामनाम परो नित्यं परानन्द विवर्द्धनः ।।

Hey Partha! I consider that country to be degenerate (reprehensible) where those who increase eternal bliss, the Vaishnav does not live chanting name of Shriram.

> रामनाम रता जीवा न पतन्ति कदाचन । इन्द्राद्यास्सम्पतन्त्यन्ते तथा
> चान्येऽधिकारिणः ॥

There is no downfall of the living beings engaged in the chanting of Shriramnam. Apart from the devotees of Sri Ram, the downfall of the Indra etc. deities and other officials is certain in the end.

> राम स्मरण मात्रेण प्राणान्मुञ्चन्ति ये नराः।
>
> फलं तेषां न पश्यामि भजामि तांश्च पार्थिव।।

Hey Rajan! The person who gives up his life just by remembering the name of Shri Ram, I does not see him but I worship him.

> नाम स्मरण मात्रेण नरो याति निरापदम्।
>
> ये स्मरन्ति सदा रामं तेषां ज्ञानेन किं फलम् ॥

By merely remembering the name of Shriram, man attains the position of Shunya Pada, those who always Remembering the name of Shri Ram, what is the use of knowledge to them?

> नामैव जगतां बन्धुर्नामैव जगतां प्रभुः।
>
> नामैव जगतां जन्म नामैव सचराचरम्॥

Shriram's name is the friend of the whole world, he is the master of all, he is the place of origin of all. That's the whole world.

> नाम्नैव धार्यते विश्वं नाम्नैव पात्यते जगत्।
>
> नाम्नैव नीयते नाम नैव भुज्यते फलम्॥

The name is very confidential and supreme it's only obtained by Shri Ram. All actions are performed through the name and fruits are obtained through the name only.

> नाम्नैव चाङ्गशास्त्राणां तात्पर्यार्थमुत्तमम् । नामैव वेद सारांश
> सिद्धान्तं सर्वदा शिवम् ॥

The best meaning of all Vedang Shastras is the name of Shri Ram and the essence of all Vedas is the name of Shri Ram that's always in the form of welfare.

> नाम्नैव नीयते मेघा परे ब्रह्मणि निश्चला ।  नाम्नैव चञ्चलं चित्तं
> मनस्तस्मिन्प्रलीयते ।।

It is only by chanting the name of Shri Ram that the unshakeable intellect can merge into the Supreme Brahman and only by chanting the name of Shri Ram, the restless mind and mind merge into the Supreme Brahman.

> श्रीरामस्मरणेनैव नरो याति पराङ्गतिम् । सत्यं सत्यं सदा सत्यं न जाने
> नामजं फलम् ।।

It is true and always true that a man attains the best Moksha only by remembering the name of Shri Ram, that even I do not know the result of taking the name of Shri Ram.

> रामनाम प्रभावोऽयं सर्वोत्तम उदाहृतः।
>
> समासेन तथा पार्थ वक्ष्येऽहं तव हेतवे।।

Hey Partha! This best effect of Sri Ramnaam has been said ultimate and I will say it again briefly for you.

> न नाम सदृशं ध्यानं न नाम सदृशो जपः।
>
> न नाम सदृशस्त्यागो न नाम सदृशी गतिः ॥
>
> न नाम सदृशं तीर्थं न नाम सदृशं तपः।
>
> न नाम सदृशं कर्म न नाम सदृशः शमः॥
>
> न नामसदृशी मुक्ति नाम सदृशः प्रभुः।
>
> ये गृह्णन्ति सदा नाम स एव जित षड्गुणाः ॥

There is no meditation, no chanting, no renunciation, no movement, no pilgrimage, no psychosis, no liberation, no power, like the name of Shri Ram, who always recite the name of Shriram In fact, they are the ones who conquer the six vices.

> कुर्वन् वा कारयन्वाऽपि रामनामजपॅंस्तथा।
>
> नीत्वा कुल सहस्राणि परंधामाधिगच्छति॥

Those who chant Shri Ramnaam or get chanted, they go to the supreme abode of God along with thousands of family members.

> नाम्नैव नीयते पुण्यं नाम्नैव नीयते तपः।
>
> नाम्नैव नीयते धर्मों जगदेतच्चराचरम् ।।

Punya is achieved by the name of Shri Ram, penance is achieved, religion is achieved, this pasture world is nurtured and organized by the name of Shri Ram.

> रामनाम प्रभावेण सर्व सिद्धीस्वरो भवेत्।
>
> विश्वासेनैव श्रीरामनाम जाप्यं सदा बुधैः।।

With the effect of Shri Ramnaam, the seeker can be the master of all achievements. That's why scholars should always chant Sri Ram's name with faith.

> शान्तो दान्तः क्षमाशीलो रामनाम परायणः।
>
> असंख्य कुलजानां वै तारणे सर्वदा क्षमः।।

Those who are calm i.e. those who have controlled their mind and Dānt i.e. those who have controlled their senses, those who are forgiving and those who recite the name of Ram, They are certainly always capable of rescuing the living beings born in innumerable clans from the ocean of material existence.

> ये नाम युक्ता विचरन्ति भूमौ त्यक्त्वाऽर्थकामान्विषयांश्च भोगान्।
>
> तेषां च भक्ति: परमा च निष्ठा सदैव शुद्धा शुभगा भवन्ती।।

Those who leave the meaning, work, subjects and pleasures and wander on the earth with the chanting of Shri Ram's name, their devotion and ultimate loyalty are always pure and beautiful.

> स्मरद्दो रामनामानि त्यक्त्वा कर्माणिचाखिलम् । स पूतः सर्वपापेभ्यः
> पद्मपत्रमिवाम्भसा ।।

One who renounces all actions and remembers the name of Shri Ram, becomes pure from all sins, just as a lotus leaf remains separate from water even after being in water, similarly it remains free from world even while living in the world.

> त्यक्त्वा श्रीरामनामानि कर्म कुर्वन्ति येऽधमाः।
>
> तेषां कर्माणि बन्धाय न सुखाय कदाचन ।।

Those who sacrifice the name of Shri Ram and perform rituals of other deeds, they are all bad, all their deeds are for the sake of bondage, that never gives happiness.

> यस्य चेतसि श्रीराममहामाङ्गलिकं परम् । स जित्वा सकलॉंल्लोकान् परंधाम
> परिव्रजेत् ॥

The one who always has the most auspicious name of Shri Ram in his mind, conquers all the worlds and attains the divine abode of God.

> नाम युक्ता जना पार्थं जात्यन्तर समन्विताः।
>
> प्रीतिं कुर्वन्ति श्रीरामं न तथा नष्ट षड्गुणाः ॥

O Partha, devotees born in low caste also love Lord Shri Ram by being united with the name of Shri Ram, the same love that those born in the best clan, who conquer the vices of lust, do not do Brahmin etc. by being devoid of Śrī Rāma.

> गायन्ति रामनामानि सततं ये जना भुवि।
>
> नमस्तेभ्यो नमस्तेभ्यो नमस्तेभ्यः पुनः पुनः॥

Salutations to those who constantly sing the name of Shri Ram on earth, salutations to them. Greetings to him again and again.

> रामनामाश्रयाये वै भावुकः प्रेम संप्लुताः।
>
> ते कृतार्थास्सदा तात सत्यं सत्यं न चान्यथा ।।

Hey Tat! Those who take refuge in the name of Shri Ram, engrossed in passionate love of God. Those people are eternally grateful, my speech is not otherwise, it is true, it is true.

> इति विज्ञापितं तात स्वया बुद्धया ।
>
> विधारय रामनाम प्रसादेन सर्वं सुखमवाप्स्यसि ।।

O Tat Arjun! Determine the secret advertised by me specifically with your intelligence, so much so that by the grace of Shriramnam you will get all the happiness.

> रामनाम जनासक्तो रामनाम जनप्रियः ।
>
> स पूतो निर्विकल्पश्च सर्वपाप बहिर्मुखः ।।

The one who is attached to lover of Śrī Rāma's name and the one who is dear to the lover Rāma's name is the most pure. He is free from all imaginations, and free from all sins.

> रामनाम प्रसगेंन वे जपन्तीह चार्जुन ।
>
> तेऽपि ध्याताखिलाघौंघा यान्ति रामास्पदं परम् ।।

O Arjuna, all the sins of those who chant the name of Sri Ram in this world even without devotion are destroyed and they too attain the divine abode of the Lord.

> घोषयेन्नाम निर्वाण कारणं यस्त्वनन्य धीः।
>
> तस्य पुण्यफलं पार्थ वक्तुं कैः शक्यते भुवि ।।

Hey Partha! Who on earth can describe the virtuous fruit of a devotee of unique intellect who chants the name of Shri Ram for salvation?

> तस्मान्नामानि कौन्तेय भजस्य दृढ चेतथा।
>
> रामनाम समायुक्तास्ते मे प्रियतमास्सदा ।।

O Arjuna, son of Kunti! Be determined and chant the names of the Lord. Those who are attached to the name of Shri Ram, they are always very dear to me.

> सततं नाम गायन्ति विनिर्विण्णेन चेतसा ।

तेषां मध्ये सदा वासः श्रीरामस्य विशेषतः।।

Those who constantly sing the name of Shri Ram without regret, Shri Ramji always resides especially in the midst of those people.

> श्रद्धया हेलया वाऽपि गायन्ति नाम मङ्गलम्।
>
> तेषां मध्ये परं नाम वसेन्नित्यं न संशयः ॥

There is no doubt that Shri Ram resides in the midst of those who chant the name of Shri Ram with reverence or even in disrespecting mood.

> न तत्र विस्मय: कार्यों भवता रामनाम्नि च ।
>
> सत्यं वदामि ते पार्थ प्रियाय मम चात्मने ।।

Hey Arjun! Don't be surprised about the significance and importance of Shri Rama. You are dear to me and my soul, so I tell you the truth.

> यन्नाम स्मरतो नित्यं महा हाज्ञान बन्धनम्।
>
> छिद्यते चाश्रमेणैव तमहं राघवं भजे ॥

I worship Lord Sri Raghavendra, whose daily remembrance of the name Rāma can breaks even the bondage of great ignorance without effort.

> श्रद्धया परया युक्तो रामनाम परायणः ।
>
> करोति जानकीजानिस्तस्य चिन्तां पुनः पुनः ।।

Lord Sri Janakinath repeatedly worries about those who are devoted to Sri Rama Naam with the utmost faith, that is, who are engaged in bhajan.

> अशेष पातकैर्युक्तः सर्वदोष परिप्लुतः ।
>
> स पूतः सर्वपापेभ्यो यस्य नाम परन्तप ।।

Enemy the enemies! O Arjuna, He who is full of all sins and who is free from all kinds of faults is also freed from all sins and becomes supremely holy.

> राम नाम सदा प्रेमा संस्मरामि जगद्गुरू ।
>
> क्षणं न विस्मृतिं याति सत्यं सत्यं वचो मम् ।।

I always remember the Jagadguru name of of Śrī Rāma with love. I do not forget for a moment that my word is truth always true.

> पर निन्दा समायुक्तः परदार परायणः।
>
> स पूतः सर्वपापेभ्यो यस्य नाम परन्तप ।।

O Parantapa Arjuna! Those who are engaged in condemning others and those who are going to go to other women are also freed from all sins who becomes connected with Sri Rama Naam.

> पर हिंसा समायुक्तो लोभ मोह समाकुलः।
>
> सः पूतः सर्वपापेभ्यो यस्य नाम्नि सदा रुचि:।।

Those who are engaged in doing violence to others and who are perfectly disturbed by greed and delusion are also freed from all sins and become supremely pure whose interest in Sri Rama Naam is always maintained.

> अशेष पातकैर्व्याप्ताः स्वधर्म परिवर्जितः।
>
> एते तरन्ति पापिष्ठा रामनाम प्रसादतः ।।

Even such sinners who are completely covered with all sins and who are void of their righteous deeds are saved by the grace of Sri Rama Naam.

> तिष्ठन्ति रामनामानि तिष्ठन्तुि वदनानि च।
>
> तथापि भरकेमूद पतन्तीत्यद्भुतं महत्।।

Lord Sri Rama has beautiful names and a beautiful face, yet fools are falling into hell. It is a great wonder.

> गायन्ति रामनामानि कर्म कुर्वन्ति चाखिलम्।
>
> स याति परमं स्थानं रामेण सह मोदते ।।

Those who perform all actions and chant Sri Rama Naam go to the divine abode and experience bliss with Sri Rama there.

> विसृज्य रामनामानि कर्म कुर्वन्ति चाखिलम् ।
>
> किमाश्चर्यं किमाश्चर्यं किमाश्चर्यं धनञ्जय ।।

O Arjuna! What is more wonderful than those who do all other deeds except the sweet names of Lord Sri Rama? All their efforts are in vain.

> शान्तोदान्तः क्षमाशीलो रामनामार्थं चिन्तकः ।
>
> तस्य सदगुण संख्य वस्तुनैव क्षमोप्यहम्॥

Even I cannot describe the number of virtues of those who meditate on the meanings of Sri Rama Naam while restraining the mind and senses.

> विसृज्य रामनामानि कर्म कुर्वन्ति ये नरः ।
>
> अप्राप्य सदगतिं पार्थ भ्रमन्ति कर्म वर्त्मसु ।।

Those who do all other karma except Sri Ramanaam do not attain Sadgati and continue to wander in the path of karma.

> सर्वयोनिषु कौन्तेय भ्रमन्ति ते नराधमाः ।
>
> विसृज्य रामनामानि माया मोहित चेतसः ॥

Those who have renounced Sri Rama Naam and have become deluded by Maya are the lowest of men, O Arjuna. They wander in all the universes.

> यदृच्छयापि श्रीरामनाम गृह्णन्ति सादरम् ।
>
> स पूतः सर्वपापेभ्यो रामनाम प्रसादतः ॥

Those who by destiny chant Sri Ramanam without love or with respect are also freed from all sins and purified by the grace of Sri Ramanam.

> येनकेन प्रकारेण नाममात्रैक जल्पकाः ।
>
> श्रमं विनैव गच्छन्ति परे धाम्नि समादरात् ॥

Those who chant only Sri Rama Naam in any way attain the divine abode of the Lord without any effort.

> नामयुक्ताञ्जनान् दृष्ट्वा यः पश्येत् सादरं सखे ।
>
> स याति परमं स्थानं रामेण सह मोदते।।

Those who see the seekers devoted of Sri Rama name and respect them, O friend Arjuna! They also go to the divine abode of Lord, Saket and experience bliss with Lord Sri Rama.

> नामयुक्ताञ्जनान् दृष्ट्वा प्रणमन्ति च ये नराः।
>
> ते पूतास्सर्वपापेभ्यः कर्मणा तेन हेतुना ।।

Those who see the devotees who are devoted to Sri Rama naam and bow down to them are freed from all sins and purified by the effect of that karma.

> नामयुक्ताञ्जनान् दृष्ट्वा स्निग्धो भवति यो नरः।
>
> स याति परमं स्थानं परमानन्द सागरम्। ।

Those whose minds are melted by seeing the devotees who are devoted to the name of Śrī Rāma also go to the divine world of the ocean of supreme bliss.

> गीत्वा च रामनामानि विचरेद्राम सन्निधौ ।
>
> इदं ब्रवीमि ते सत्यं तस्य वश्यो जगत्पतिः॥

Those who continue to wander near Sri Rama while chanting Sri Rama Naam, that is, who continue to circumambulate the Lord while chanting Bhagavan Naam, O Arjuna! I tell you the truth that God becomes subject to that devotee.

> गीत्वा च रामनामानि ये रुदन्ति नरोत्तमाः ।
>
> तेषां हरिः परिक्रीतो परमेशेन संयुतः ॥

I am sold with Lord Sri Rama at the hands of the best man who keeps crying while chanting Sri Rama Naam, that is, I become under his control.

> गीत्वा च रामनामेति पतन्ति भुवि ये नराः ।
>
> ते वै धन्यातिधन्याश्च वैष्णवानां शिरोमणिः ।।

Those who fall to the ground while chanting Sri Rama Naam are blessed and foremost among Vaishnavas.

> यदृच्छया न गृह्णन्ति रामनामेति मङ्गलम्।
>
> अदृश्यास्ते जनाः पार्थ दृष्टिमात्रेण वर्जिताः ।।

Those who do not even by destiny utter the most auspicious Sri Rama Naam, O Arjuna! One should not see such people. If one ever comes forward, one should turn away or close one's eyes. This means that seeing the faces of averse people brings sinful heat from conversation and touch. Therefore, one should be careful.

> स्वप्नेऽपि रामनाम्नस्तु येषामुच्चारणं नहि।
>
> भाग्यहीनास्तु ते नीचाः पापिनामग्रगामिनः।।

Those whose mouths have not uttered Sri Rama Naam even in a dream are unfortunate, lowly and foremost among the sinners.

> भिक्षया ये न गृह्णन्ति रामनाम परमेश्वरम् । लोकोपचारनिरतास्ते वै
> पाखण्डिनो ध्रुवम्।।

Those who do not utter Sri Rama Naam for the sake of almsgiving, that is, for fear that if they say Sri Rama Naam, they will not get alms, they are bound by worldly desires and are certainly hypocrites.

> रामनाम जपाज्जीवा अनायासेन संसृतिम् ।
>
> तरन्त्येव तरन्त्येव तरन्त्येव सुनिश्चितम्।।

By chanting Sri Rama Naam, the beings are surely saved from the cycle of the world without effort.

**तत्रैवार्जुनवाक्यं श्रीकृष्णं प्रति~
"Therefore Arjuna's words to Krishna"~**

> भवत्येव भवत्येव भवत्येव महामते।
>
> सर्वपाप परिव्याप्तास्तरन्ति नामबान्धवाः ॥

O great intellectual! It is as you said it is. If one who is full of sin takes Sri Rama Naam as his own, he will surely cross the ocean of death.

> नमोस्तु नामरूपाय नमोस्तु नामजल्पिने ।
>
> नमोस्तु नाम साध्याय वेदवेद्याय शाश्क्ते ।।

Obeisance to the transcendental form of Sri Rama Naam, salutations to those who chant Sri Rama Naam, and salutations to the indestructible Lord Sri Rama, who is represented by all the Vedas as the ultimate achievable fruit of Sri Rama Naam.

> नमोस्तु नाम नित्याय नमो नामप्रभाविने ।
>
> नमोस्तु नामशुद्धाय नमो नाममयाय च।।

Obeisance to the eternal, supremely effective, supremely pure and all-named Sri Rama Naam.

> श्रीरामनाम माहात्म्यं यः पठेच्छ्रद्धयान्वितः ।
>
> स याति परमं स्थानं रामनाम प्रसादतः।।

Whoever reads the greatness of Sri Rama Naam with devotion will attain the highest place by the grace of Sri Rama Naam.

> रामनामार्थमुत्कृष्टं पवित्रं पावनं परम् ।
>
> ये ध्यायन्ति सदा स्नेहात्ते कृतार्था : जगत्त्रये ।।

Those who always contemplate the excellent, holy and most sacred meanings of Sri Rama Naam with affection are blessed in the three worlds.

**इति आदि पुराणे श्रीकृष्ण-अर्जुन संवादे श्रीराम नाम महात्म्य संपूर्णम्**

As my mother tongue is Hindi I face problem in writing my answers in English, so please forgive this servent for any mistake.

In Śrīmad Rāmcharit Mānas it is said by Śrīmad Goswami Tulsidas ji Maharaj,

**Hari Anant Hari Katha Ananta..**

Glory of the name of Śrī Rāma is infinite as Lord is infinite.

Please Chant SitaRam SitaRam ❤️

Hail to Priya Pritam Sarkar ❤️

Hail to Ānand Bhāshyakār Śrīmad Jagādgurü Ramānandacharya

Answer (score 1):

Let's see it 1st from a different perspective then we will go into the meaning of the name itself.:

Lord Hanuman is a great devotee of Lord Rama, so he always sings his glories.

**In Parāśara Samhītā Nar and Narayana are said to be the form of Hanuman ji only.:**

> *पुरा वदरिकारण्ये नरनारायणाकृतिः भवान्बभूव भूतात्मा स्वरूपध्यानतत्परः ।। 81 ।।*
>
> *You (Hanuman), are the soul of all living ones, were once performing meditation and penance in the Jujube Forest (present Badarināth) as Nara and Nārāyaṇa in respective forms.*

We all know that Nara = Arjuna and Narayana = Krishna.

As for Lord Rama,

**Rama Rahasya Upanishad.:**

> *“राम.न त्रिनेत्र.न सोमर्धरिण.न शुउलिनं परम.ह भस्मोढुलित्सर्व~ंगाईं कपर्दिन्मुपसंहे |ध्याननेव.न वर्णलक्ष.न जपतर्पण नत्परः |बिल्वपत्रै: फलाई: पुष्पपिष्टलज्यै: पान~नकजैर्हुनातेः। (रामरहस्योपनिषद् 2.32, 2.34).*
>
> *"I worship Rama, who has three eyes, who wears the crescent moon, who bears the trident, who is anointed with ashes, and who has the matted hair. Meditating thus, completely recite  And the person dedicated to the offering should chant the mantras one lakh times while offering bilva leaves, fruits, flowers, gingelly seeds and lotus”.*

It clearly shows Rama as the three eyed Lord Mahadeva! The next verse speaks about Sita Devi as follows.

> *"raamaabhiraamaa.n saundaryasiimaa.n somaavata.nsikaam.h
> paashaa~NkushadhanurbaaNadharaa.n dhyaayettrilochanaam.h " (Rama Rahasya Upanishad Ch 2, Verse 33).*
>
> *"I worship the three eyed one, Who is Abhirama, the pinnacle of beauty,
> Who wears the crescent as ear ring, And who holds the noose, the goad, the bow and the arrow".*

It clearly shows Sita (Abhirama) as the Goddess LALITA TRIPURA SUNDARI the consort of Sadashiva.

***"Ramou vigrahavan dharmah"*** is another verse from Valmiki Ramayana which states that ***Lord Rama is the epitome or human form of Dharma (Righteousness).*** Rama never departs from Dharma. He is full of Dharma and he follows it religiously without any deviation. There is not even a single event in Rama's life which is Adharmic.

Who actually represents Dharma? As per Shruti, Dharma is lord Shiva only.:

> *"dharmo rudro..." (Rudrahridayopanishad 1:16).*
>
> ***"Rudra is Dharma".***

So, Lord Krishna = Lord Hanuman and Lord Rama = Lord Shiva.

> *“Yuge yuge thu krushnena thoshitho vai maheswara | Bhakthya paramaya chaiva prathi sruthwa mahatmana |” (MBH 13:14:13).*
>
> *“In every new Yuga has Krishna (by such penances) gratified Mahadeva. In every Yuga has Mahadeva been gratified with the great devotion of the high-souled Krishna“.*

> *satyaśaucārjava tyāgais tapasā niyamena ca kṣāntyā bhaktyā ca dhṛtyā ca buddhyā ca vacasā tathā ( Mh Bhar 10.7.60).*
>
> *yathāvad aham ārāddhaḥ kṛṣṇenākliṣṭakarmaṇā tasmād iṣṭatamaḥ kṛṣṇād anyo mama na vidyate ( Mh Bhar 10.07.61).*
>
> *"With truth, purity, sincerity, resignation, ascetic austerities, vows, forgiveness, devotion, patience, thought, and word, I (Shiva) have been duly adored by Krishna of pure deeds. For this there is none dearer to me than Krishna".*

Now, as for the Rama Nama or Taraka Mantra.: It is said that Rama Nama is bigger than Lord Rama himself.

- **Taraka Mantra.:**

> *"atha hainaM bhaaradvaajaH paprachchha yaaj~navalkya.n ki.n taaraka.n ki.n taarayatiiti " (Ramatapini Upanishad-Poorvopanishat 6.2).*
>
> *"Sage Bharadwaja enquired Yajnyavalkya.: - 'What is Taraka? What is the one which liberates?"*
>
> ***Yajnyavalkya replied.:***
>
> *"akaaraH prathamaaksharo bhavati ukaarodvitiiyaaksharo bhavati. makaarastR^itiiyaaksharo
> bhavati. ardhamaatrashchaturthaaksharo bhavati binduH pa~nchamaaksharo bhavati naadaH shhashhThaaksharo bhavati . taarakatvaattaarako bhavati.
> tadeva taarakaM brahma tva.n viddhi . tadevopaasitavyamiti j~neyam.h . garbhajanmajaraamaraNasa.nsaaramahadbhayaatsa.ntaarayatiiti .
> tasmaaduchyate shhaDakshara.n taarakamiti . . ya etattaarakaM brahma braahmaNo nityamadhiite . sa paapmaana.n tarati . sa mR^ityu.n tarati .
> sa brahmahatyaa.n tarati . sa bhruuNahatyaa.n tarati. sa sa.nsaara.n tarati . sa sarva.n tarati . so.avimuktamaashrito bhavati . sa mahaanbhavati . so.amR^itatva.n cha gachchhati " (Ramatapini Upanishad-Poorvopanishat 6.2).*
>
> ***"That which has 'A' as the first syllable, 'U' as the second syllable, 'M' the third syllable, half-note is the fourth syllable, dot is the fifth syllable, and sound is the sixth syllable; that is called the Taraka.** That when practiced liberates one from the cycles of births and deaths. **This is verily the ' Shadakshara (Six letered)' Taraka mantra namely Omkara.** That person who regularly utters this Mantra, he gets ferried from sins, he gets ferried from death, he gets absolved of the sins like Brahmahatya (killing of brahmana), killing of foetus, he gets ferried from the ocean of Samsaara, **he gets liberated from everything, he becomes one with the Avimukta (Lord Shiva as the redeemer), he becomes great, he becomes immortal".***

Now, Who is this TARAKA Mantra OMKARA.:

> *"nama staraya cha" (Yajurveda Sri Rudram Anuvaka-8).*
>
> *"Salutations to Him (Rudra) who is the TARAKA (Pravana mantra - Om)".*

> *"atha kasmAduchyata o~NkAro yasmAduchchAryamANa eva
> prANAnUrdhvamutkrAmayati tasmAduchyate o~NkAraH " (Atharvasiras Upanishad 3:07).*
>
> *"Rudra is called the personification of Pranva because he sends the souls towards heaven, at the time of death (dissolution)".*

> *"atha kasmAduchyate praNavaH yasmAduchchAryamANa eva
> R^igyajuHsAmAtharvA~Ngirasa.n brahma brAhmaNebhyaH praNAmayati
> nAmayati cha tasmAduchyate praNavaH " (Atharvasiras Upanishad 3:08).*
>
> *"He (Rudra) is called the “one who has the shape of Pranava“, because the Brahmins read and propagate the Rik, Yajur, Sama and Atharva Vedas only after reading 'OM'".*

> *"atha kasmAduchyate tAra.n yasmAduchchAramANa eva
> garbhajanmavyAdhijarAmaraNasa.nsAramahAbhayAttArayati trAyate
> cha tasmAduchyate tAram.h " (Atharvasiras Upanishad 3:10).*
>
> *"He (Rudra)is called “Tara (Taraka - Liberator)” because he protects one from the fear of life which consists of the fear of staying in the womb, fear at time of birth, fear from diseases, fear from old age and fear from death".*

> *"umaasahaayaM parameshvaraM prabhuM trilochanaM niilakaNThaM prashaantam.h
> dhyaatvaa munirgachchhati bhuutayoniM samastasaakShiM tamasaH parastaat.h " (Kaivalya Upanishad 7).*
>
> *"Meditating on the highest Lord, allied to Uma, powerful, three-eyed, blue-necked, and tranquil, the holy man reaches Him (Rudra) who is the source of all, the witness of all and is beyond darkness (i.e. Avidya)".*

> *"sa eva sarvaM yadbhuutaM yachcha bhavyaM sanaatanam.h
> j~naatvaa taM mR^ityumatyeti naanyaH panthaa vimuktaye "(Kaivalya Upanishad 9).*
>
> *"He (Rudra) alone is all that was, and all that will be, the Eternal; **knowing Him (Rudra), one transcends death; there is no other way to liberation".***

> *"atra hi jantoH praaNeshhuutkramamaaNeshhu rudrastaarakaM brahma
> vyaachashhTe yenaasaavamR^itii bhuutvaa mokshii bhavati
> tasmaadavimuktameva nishheveta avimukta.n na
> vimu~nchedevamevaitadyaaj~navalkyaH " (Jabala Upanishad 1.1).*
>
> *"This is the spot where, when the vital airs depart from the living person, Rudra imparts the mantra (Taraka Brahman) to him by which, becoming immortal, he attains liberation".*

So from these references it is clear that TARAKA mantram is OM (Pranava) which is lord Rudra (Shiva) in mantra form. And Shiva whisphers this OM mantra in Kashi and liberates the dying person.

> *“To understand the meaning of the Pranava is to understand Me [says Shiva]. The Pranava is the seed of all the lores. It shall be understood as very subtle but possessed of great meaning even as the seed of the banyan tree though very small contains a huge tree. It is the initial mantra and the essence of the Vedas. Particularly it has Me [Shiva] for its form. I am Shiva pervading all but stationed in the single-syllabled mantra Om. Whatever object there is, whether synthesized into one or analyzed in parts, is the meaning of the Pranava. It is the imperishable Brahman, the means of attaining all objects. Shiva creates the universe at the outset, saying ‘Om.’ Shiva is the Pranava and the Pranava is Shiva. The brahmin sages, the wise who realize the identity between the word and what it indicates know me as the single-syllabled Om. Hence he who aspires for salvation and is free from aberration shall understand the Pranava as the cause of all, and Me as the Nirguna Parameshwara. **I give this crest-jewel of mantras at Kashi for the liberation of all individual souls.”** (Shiva Purana, Kailashasamhita 3:2-10).*

Plus, its Lord Shiva only who transends this Taraka/Pranava/Shabda/Akshara/Vāk Brahman means OM and is both Vaikahari and Silence.

> *"kaa.nsyaghaNTaaninaadastu yathaa liiyati shaantaye | o~Nkaarastu tathaa yojyaH shaantaye sarvamichchhataa | yasminviliiyate shabdastatparaM brahma giiyate | dhiya.n hi liiyate brahma so.amR^itatvaaya kalpate |" (Brahmavidya Upanishad 12-13).*
>
> *"And just as the sound of a metal utensil – or of a gong dies in silence – so he, who seeks the All lets the OM sound fade away in silence. For that wherein the sound fades away is the Brahman, the higher. Yea, the whole sound is Brahman and conduces to immortality”.*

> *"yo vedaadau svaraH prokto vedaante cha pratishhThitaH | tasya prakR^itiliinasya yaH paraH sa maheshvaraH " (Taittiriya Aranyaka 10.12.3.17).*
>
> *"It is Lord Maheshwara who transcends the syllable Om which is uttered at the commencement of the recital of the Vedas, which is well established in the vEdAnta (Upanishads) and which is dissolved in the primal cause during contemplation".*

- **RaMa Nama.:**

The name RaMa not only belongs to Lord Dasarathi Rama, as before him there was another Rama viz the Rama of Bharghava clan aka Parshu Rama and after him also there was another Rama viz the Rama of Yadava clan aka Bala Rama. Now, What's the meaning of the name RAMA.:

RAMA = RA + MA. The mantram "RAMA" is composed of a combination of Rakaram (RA) which is AgniRoopakam (of the form of Agni) and Makaaram (MA) which is Amrutaroopakam (of the form of Amruta).

**Rama Rahasya Upanishad.:**

> *"The true meaning of the king among the Rama mantras, as well as of the eight-lettered Narayana and five-lettered Shiva mantras, is spoken of as thus: Where yogi-s revel in the 2 syllable mantra viz. ‘Ra ma’ where the **ra syllable denotes fire wherein abides illumination**..... **The sound ' ma ' , is known as ' maya (Prakriti/Soma)' indicating prosperity ;** being itself the seed - letter ( bijakshara ) is also equal to Brahman itself .*

Now, if we analyze this combination of Agni and Amurta it is nothing but "Neela-Lohitah" (Lord Shiva). Lord Shiva is called Neelalohita since he is of Red and Blue-Black form having a combination of Agni and Amruta Tatwams. Shiva is Agni tatwam, and Uma is Amruta tatwam. hence they being one as Ardhanareeshwara they are Neela -bluish-black (Uma) and Lohitah - Blazing-Red (Shiva). This entire world is a manifested form of this Neelalohitah (Agni and Soma) or KrishnaPinglam. In this connection Rudra Hridayopanishat says:

> *"yaa umaa saa svaya.n vishhNuryo vishhNuH sa hi chandramaaH
> yo rudraH sa svayaM brahmaa yo brahmaa sa hutaashanaH
> brahmavishhNumayo rudra agniishhomaatka.n jagat.h " (Rudra hridayopanishad 1: 5,8,9).*
>
> ***"Uma is herself in the form of Vishnu and Vishnu is himself in the form of Chandrama (Soma). Rudra is himself in the form of Brahma and Brahma is in the form of Hutasana (Fire). This whole world is a combination of Agni and Soma (Amruta)".***

From the above verses it is clear that whole world is of the form of Uma (Amruta tatwam)-Maheshwara (Agni tatwam). This same fact has been symbolically ascribed to Sita Rama in below verses.

> *"atra raamo vahninaa samaH (Here Rama is like Fire)" (Rama Poorva Tapini Upanishad 3:5).*
>
> *"siitayaa bhaati chandrashchandrikayaa yathaa (Sita shines as like as Moon)". (Rama Poorva Tapini Upanishad 3:6).*
>
> *"agniishhomaatmaka.n jagat.h (This whole world is a combination of Agni and Amruta)". (Rama Poorva Tapini Upanishad 3:6. Same as Rudra hridayopanishad-1:9).*

**So, RAMA nama is essentially the combination of Shiva and Shakti in Mantra form. Shiva and Shakti being inseparably united as Ardhanareeshwara, RAMA nama is nothing but Lord Shiva (Ardhanareeshwara) in Mantra form. And since we have already read that Shiva is himself Pranavam. Hence Shiva in the form of RAMA nama makes RAMA nama equal to Pranavam.**

**Therefore RAMA name is TARAKAM because it is nothing but embodiment of Lord Ardhanareeshwara (Shiva) in Mantra form. This proves that the indweller of RAMA mantra is Lord Shiva. Hence all glories of Rama mantra are actually the glories of Lord Shiva.**

**That's why it's called *"Rama Nama Satya Hain"* because *"Satyam Shivam Sundaram"* and some times people also say that Lord Rudra does Rama Nama Japa it's because it's his own name and self viz Pranava.**

> *“Sarve Rudram Bhajantyeva Rudrah Kinchid Bhajennahi Svaatmana Bhaktavaatsalyaad Bhajatyeva kadachana" (Shiva Purana, Kotirudra Samhita 7:15).*
>
> ***"Everyone worships Rudra but Rudra doesn’t worship anyone. For the sake of devotees he meditates on himself”.***

I hope this clarifies all queries. Prd..